# how to create nettcpbinding of this custombinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I am new at WCF programming model and I want to use `netTcpBinding`. Before I ask my question below this is my custom binding :

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="basic">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate"/>
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

When I create a service reference using a simple console application it finds a certificate and ask me to use it. And this way I can use the webservice ...

But when I change binding to `netTcpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential` the service is looking for certificate and could not find it like this :

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name ="sdfsd">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

---

```
ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Contoso.com").
```

At this point I use a `CustomNameValidator` and I do it programmatically.

So when I use `netTcpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential`, why does the call to `SetCertificate` not find the installed certificate? Am I missing something ? Or do I have to add something?

Answer (score 0):

ok guys...sorry but some of the message is miising ...
my custom binding  is 
customBinding

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="basic">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate"/>
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

and netTcpBing that i tried to convert  is :

```
   <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name ="sdfsd">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>

    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```